# Unusual ambiguous error

Tags: haskell

In the following code [(ideone link)](http://ideone.com/AextPg), why does line (1) fail when line (4) compiles without issue [(ideone link with line (1) commented)](http://ideone.com/vqfZko):

```
data DataOrError a b = Error a | Data b deriving Show

apply f (Data x) (Data y) = Data (f x y)
apply f (Data x) y@(Error _) = y
apply f x@(Error _) _ = x

main = do
  print (apply (+) x1 x2) -- (1)
  print (apply (+) x1 e2) -- (2)
  print (apply (+) e1 x2) -- (3)
  print (apply (+) e1 e2) -- (4)
  where
    x1 = Data (2 :: Int)
    x2 = Data (3 :: Int)
    e1 = Error ("First thing failed")
    e2 = Error ("Second thing failed")
```

I know `DataOrError` is basically `Either`, this is just for illustration.

The error is:

```
prog.hs:8:3:
    No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (DataOrError a b)
        -- Defined at prog.hs:1:50
      instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      ...plus 24 others
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (apply (+) x1 x2)
    In the expression:
      do { print (apply (+) x1 x2);
           print (apply (+) x1 e2);
           print (apply (+) e1 x2);
           print (apply (+) e1 e2) }
    In an equation for `main':
        main
          = do { print (apply (+) x1 x2);
                 print (apply (+) x1 e2);
                 print (apply (+) e1 x2);
                 .... }
          where
              x1 = Data (2 :: Int)
              x2 = Data (3 :: Int)
              e1 = Error ("First thing failed")
              e2 = Error ("Second thing failed")
```

Comment: Error and ideone link now included

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing an error because the derived instance for `Show (DataOrError a b)` looks like

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (DataOrError a b) where
    ...
```

Notice that both `a` and `b` have to be `Show` instances for `DataOrError` to have its instance.  The type of `x1` and `x2` is `DataOrError a Int` and for `e1` and `e2` the type is `DataOrError String b`.  This means that the other type variable for `DataOrError` isn't constrained to `Show`.  You can fix this with explicit type parameters:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (apply (+) x1 x2) -- (1)
  print (apply (+) x1 e2) -- (2)
  print (apply (+) e1 x2) -- (3)
  print (apply (+) e1 e2) -- (4)
  where
    x1 = Data 2                      :: DataOrError String Int
    x2 = Data 3                      :: DataOrError String Int
    e1 = Error "First thing failed"  :: DataOrError String Int
    e2 = Error "Second thing failed" :: DataOrError String Int
```

You can put anything there, including `()`, for the type variable you're not using so long as it's an instance of `Show`.  The only reason why this happens is that the compiler is trying to be helpful and is inferring that the parameter you haven't specified is more general than you actually want it to be.  While you can tell that it shouldn't matter, the compiler doesn't look at the values to determine if something can be printed, it looks at the types.

The reason why you don't see an error on line 4 but you do on line 1 is because of defaulting.  For lines 2 and 3 it can figure out the full type of the return value of `apply (+)`, but on line 4 the compiler only knows that it has to be `Num a`.  It then chooses to default this to `Integer`, which I misinterpreted at first as an error because I always compile with warnings as errors.

Comment: So why does line (4) compile without issue and not (1)? Actually doing your suggestion with just `x1` fixes the problem, `e1` and `e2` work without issue.

Comment: @Clinton Throws an error for me.  What version of GHC are you using?

Comment: @Clinton Oh, nevermind, the reason is that when you have `apply (+) x1 x2`, the type variable is still unknown, when you have a mixture of `xN` and `eN`, that concretes both type variables.  If you add a full type signature to `x1`, you should get an error on line 4.  At least I do.

Comment: Have you checked the ideone link? No error at line 4.

Comment: @Clinton I have to admit a bit of an embarrassment, I saw it as an error because my build system flagged it in my IDE, but it's just a warning.  I just have gotten used to treating warnings as errors.  If you compile with `-Wall` in GHC you'll see that the variable is getting defaulted to `Integer`, because the compiler knows it has to be `Num` from the use of `(+)`.  If you had `print (apply (++) e1 e2)` it does actually throw an error, since `++` doesn't constrain that type variable enough for it to be defaulted.